# Create input for injectOperation (forged op + Beacon Wallet signature)

Tags: taquito, operation, inject, beacon

I'm trying to manually forge a transaction, sign it with Beacon Wallet and inject it.

I've forged and sign it. preapplyOperations is OK.

Now I'm trying to build the input data for injectOperation using all I got from previous steps.

```
// 1. operation
    const operation = {
        branch: branch,
        contents: [
            {
                kind: opTxKind,
                source: userAddress,
                destination: userAddress,
                amount: "1",
                fee: estimated.suggestedFees,
                counter: counter,
                gas_limit: estimated.gasLimit,
                storage_limit: estimated.storageLimit
            }
        ]
    };
    
    // 2. forge operation
    const forgedBytes: string = await Tezos.rpc.forgeOperations(operation);
    
    // 3. sign with beacon wallet
    const payload: RequestSignPayloadInput = {
        signingType: SigningType.OPERATION,
        payload: '03' + forgedBytes,
        sourceAddress: userAddress,
    };

    const signedPayload = await wallet.client.requestSignPayload(payload);
    const { signature } = signedPayload; // get the edsig... signature
    
    // 4. preapply
    const preapplyParams = { ...operation, protocol, signature };
    const preapplyResponse = await Tezos.rpc.preapplyOperations([preapplyParams]);
```

As explained here (https://ocamlpro.com/blog/2018_11_21_an_introduction_to_tezos_rpcs_signing_operations), I try to do that:

```
const opHash = await Tezos.rpc.injectOperation(forgedBytes + b58decode(signature));
```

But it does not work:

```
HttpResponse: Http error response: (500) [{"kind":"temporary","id":"failure","msg":"Invalid operation opQM3tVn6UgLjcDTFJ5fdsR3oaDhGgRVaknCitovMJMJQNeHH6R: \nError:\n  Operation parsing error in prevalidation.\n."}]
```

Can you help me to create the input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you slice the prefix from the signature

The example bellow can be improved.

```
export const sign = async (wallet: BeaconWallet, bytes: string) => {
    const result = await wallet.client.requestSignPayload({
        signingType: SigningType.OPERATION,
        payload: '03' + bytes,
    });

    let sbytes = bs58check.decode(result.signature);
    if (result.signature.startsWith('edsig') || result.signature.startsWith('spsig1')) {
        sbytes = sbytes.slice(5).toString('hex');
    } else if (result.signature.startsWith('p2sig')) {
        sbytes = sbytes.slice(4).toString('hex');
    } else {
        sbytes = sbytes.slice(3).toString('hex');
    }

    return `${bytes}${sbytes}`;
};
```

```
const opHash = await Tezos.rpc.injectOperation(sign(...));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!